# Incompatibility between tkz-linknodes and babel

Tags: babel, incompatibility, tkz-collection

I'm using `tkz-linknodes` package along with `babel` (greek language selected).

When the packages are both loaded I get the error:

```
You can't use `the character 1' after \the. \begin
Missing \endcsname inserted. \begin
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \begin
Extra \endcsname. \begin
Argument of \@gobble has an extra }. \end{gather*}
Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete. \end{gather*}
No counter 'C@Node{\greekscript \GenericWarning {(babel) fined. \end{gather*}
Paragraph ended before \@gobble was complete. \end{gather*}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{gather*}
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{gather*}
Extra \endcsname. \end{gather*}
Illegal value (0) for greeknumeral.
Command \greekscript invalid in math mode
```

and several other. When I comment the `babel` package the linknodes work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{nimbusserif,tikz,amsmath}
\usepackage{tkz-linknodes}

\begin{document}
\begin{NodesList}
\begin{gather*}
x+1=2\Rightarrow \AddNode\\
x=1\AddNode
\end{gather*}
\LinkNodes{greek text / (κείμενο)}%
\end{NodesList}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the package is no longer in texlive as the author has taken it out of circulation because of various problems: https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-linknodes

Comment: I see. Is there an alternative package?